# Divergence as infinitesimal volume change on a Finsler manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, measure-theory, flows, finsler-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $Z$ a smooth vector field on it.
It generates a family of diffeomorphisms $\phi_t:M\to M$ by demanding that $\phi_0=\operatorname{id}$ and $\partial_t\phi_t(x)=Z(\phi_t(x))$.
(Local properties are enough for me, but you can make things work globally if $M$ is, say, closed.)
I want to understand how these diffeomorphisms change a volume measure or form for small $t$.

The Riemannian case was simple enough for me.
If $dVol_g$ is the volume measure of a Riemannian metric $g$, there are smooth positive functions $f_t(x)$ so that $dVol_{\phi^*_tg}(x)=f_t(x)dVol_g(x)$.
A calculation shows that
$$
\partial_tf_t(x)|_{t=0}
=
\operatorname{div}(Z)(x),
\tag{1}
$$
so the divergence of $Z$ describes the infinitesimal volume change of displacement by the vector field $Z$.

What happens when I have a volume measure arising from a Finsler metric $F$ on $M$?
There are different volume forms; I have heard of Busemann–Hausdorff and Holmes–Thompson, but there may be others.
What kinds of divergences do the different volume forms correspond to in this sense?
Or is there a volume form corresponding to a natural Finsler divergence so that (1) holds?

In short:
Is there a Finsler setting (measure and divergence) where (1) works?

Comment: Once a smooth volume is given (in the form of a n-form $\mu$) the divergence is well defined through the Lie derivative $L_Z\mu = div(Z) \mu$, and it describes the  infinitesimal change of volume through the flow of Z as in the Riemannian case. No matter where $\mu$ comes from, it is only a differential concept.

Comment: @Raziel That sounds promising! Every volume form gives rise to a concept of divergence. But then the question is: Are both $\mu$ and $\operatorname{div}(Z)$ some canonical Finsler objects? (In the Riemannian case the canonical choice for both objects satisfies that condition.) Or if one starts with any of the Finsler volume forms, what is the resulting concept of divergence?

Comment: As I said before, once a volume is fixed, the divergence is uninquely defined by the formula $L_Z \mu = div_\mu(Z) \mu$, provided that $\mu$ is regular enough (C^1 is enough). If \mu is a "canonical Finsler objetct", then also $div_mu$ will be.